# How do I send PGP/MIME email with gpg?

Tags: gnupg

I know how to use gpg to send PGP/MIME messages? That is, if I have a MIME message, how to I tell gpg to wrap it? When messages are signed and encrypted, is everything inside the encrypted envelope?

Comment: GnuPG does not know about MIME. Handling MIME is the job of the MUA, GnuPG is no mail client. For this question the same applies as for your other one: this does not seem to be a development question but about general tool usage, and thus is off topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: openssl handles MIME. I'm writing a program that sends MIME using gpg, so I need to know where to do the MIME processing.